# Nombre no definido, pero si lo he definido

Tags: python

Tengo este codigo, pero al compilar me dice que guess no esta definido, cuando esta un par de lineas arriba. He probado de todo, pongo el codigo original (no es mio) por que ya no se ni lo que había hecho:

```
from fractions import Fraction
def sampled_freq_to_period(sampled_freq, num_freqs, max_period):
f = Fraction(sampled_freq, num_freqs)
r = f.limit_denominator(max_period)
return r.denominator
guess = sampled_freq_to_period(sampled_freq=171,
                           num_freqs=1024,
                           max_period=21)
print(guess)
```

Comment: Hola, ese código parece python y python no se compila ya que es un lenguaje interpretado, me imagino que te referirás a cuando lo intentas ejecutar. ¿Nos podrías copiar el error?

Comment: El código no está correctamente indentado, por lo que no es fácil adivinar donde termina la función. Supongo que en el `return`. ¿Podrías editar la pregunta y corregir la indentación? Lee antes lo que se explica aquí: https://bit.ly/SOesPASTE

Answer (score 0):

me parece que el error es que no identaste la función, por eso cuando declaras la variable 'guees' lo reconoce como si estuviera dentro de función lo cual no es leída hasta que sea llamada en todo caso sería algo así

```
from fractions import Fraction
def sampled_freq_to_period(sampled_freq, num_freqs, max_period):
    f = Fraction(sampled_freq, num_freqs)
    r = f.limit_denominator(max_period)
    return r.denominator

guess = sampled_freq_to_period(sampled_freq=171,
                           num_freqs=1024,
                           max_period=21)
print(guess)
    introducir el código aquí
```

Comment: Y por fin?? @neok, te funcionó esta respuesta??